A typo in Higher Algebra?
I am not sure whether it's a typo or I understand it in the wrong way: in 7.1.3.18 of Lurie's Higher Algebra, he states :

I feel like in the proposition 7.1.3.18,  all notations $Alg_{R}^{(k)}$ should be replaced by $Alg_{R}^{(k),dic)}$?

Yes, I think so. That's what the proof refers to and the statement doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Why don't you post this as an answer? It is an answer.
